# Is there a standard color for a 'Share by email' icon for web?

Tags: website-design, color, icon

This is a question which has always been floating around my brain when putting the final touches on a website. (And I couldn't find much about it on the web)

When using social icons in the context of sharing content, e.g. sharing a blog post, and Email is one of the methods of sharing, what colour should the Email icon be when all the other icons are coloured by their branding (somewhat)?

[image: Example social icons]

Does anyone have any examples and/or rationale for using a particular colour, if one exists universally for 'Share by email'?

Comment: Since email is not a product with a brand, there is no particular color for it in the context of other social product icons. Pick whatever you think looks good.

Answer (score 1):

There is no real standard but I did some extensive research when making a vector set for my sites and the majority used on sites were yellow. I figured if thats what the majority is using, why not go with it. The less you make a user think, the better.

This may be caused by Outlook(the email program) have used it has its brand color for years, but that's strictly conjecture.

example..

[image]